# HTML - favicon not working when using domain but does when going straight to server

Tags: html, favicon

I have added a favicon icon to my site. I have this in my header:

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="ico" href="favicon.ico"/>
```

When connecting to my website using the ip x.x.x.x.x/index.html it shows up fine, but when going through my domain name it does not show.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Clear browser cache and temporary internet files, close the browser and open it again.

Comment: Which browser are you using? Wikipedia has the best information I have found for support: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Favicon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe it's a cache issue.
Try refreshing your browser with

```
control+F5
```

Comment: What is the website link? so we can try it out (:
if you open the source code of the page does it link to the correct image?

Comment: I can see it in chrome fine but firefox won't have it.

Comment: a post related to firefox only says clear your cache: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1319766/why-wont-favicon-load-in-firefox

Comment: Please tick the answere as solution so others can benefit from your question :)